# tf_agents reset environment using actor

Tags: python, tensorflow, openai-gym, tf-agent

I'm trying to understand how to use `Actor` class in tf_agents. I am using DDPG (actor-critic, although this doesn't really matter per say). I also am learning off of `gym` package, although again this isn't fully important to the question.

I went into the class definition for `train.Actor` and under the hood the run method calls py_driver.PyDriver. It is my understanding that after it reaches a terminal state, the gym environment needs to be reset. However following the Actor and PyDriver classes, I don't see anywhere (outside the init method) where env.reset() is called. And then looking at the tutorial for `sac_agent.SacAgent`, I don't see them calling env.reset() either.

Can someone help me understand what is missing? Do I not need to call env.reset()? Or is there some code that is being called that I am missing?

Here is the method for PyDriver.run():

```
  def run(
      self,
      time_step: ts.TimeStep,
      policy_state: types.NestedArray = ()
      ) -> Tuple[ts.TimeStep, types.NestedArray]:
      
      num_steps = 0
      num_episodes = 0
      while num_steps < self._max_steps and num_episodes < self._max_episodes:
          # For now we reset the policy_state for non batched envs.
          if not self.env.batched and time_step.is_first() and num_episodes > 0:
               policy_state = self._policy.get_initial_state(self.env.batch_size or 1)

          action_step = self.policy.action(time_step, policy_state)
          next_time_step = self.env.step(action_step.action)

          # When using observer (for the purpose of training), only the previous
          # policy_state is useful. Therefore substitube it in the PolicyStep and
          # consume it w/ the observer.
          action_step_with_previous_state = action_step._replace(state=policy_state)
          traj = trajectory.from_transition(time_step, action_step_with_previous_state, next_time_step)
          for observer in self._transition_observers:
              observer((time_step, action_step_with_previous_state, next_time_step))
          for observer in self.observers:
              observer(traj)
          for observer in self.info_observers:
              observer(self.env.get_info())

          if self._end_episode_on_boundary:
              num_episodes += np.sum(traj.is_boundary())
          else:
              num_episodes += np.sum(traj.is_last())

          num_steps += np.sum(~traj.is_boundary())

          time_step = next_time_step
          policy_state = action_step.state

     return time_step, policy_state
```

As you can see, it increases the number of steps if it hits a boundary, and increases the number of episodes if it hits the terminal state. But then there is no call to `env.reset()`.

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? Furthermore, `env.reset()` is called at the start of an episode (or at the end of an episode) to reset the environment, maybe reset the location of the agent and return you the current (new) observation along with some info. If it is not present here, you should add it somewhere in between episodes: maybe just before you call `run()`?

Comment: These are the class definitions within tf_agents itself. I was lookint at the SAC tutorial. https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/7_SAC_minitaur_tutorial. I don't see anywhere in the underlying code for the actor where reset is called which as you pointed out is important. PyDriver is called under the hood when using an Actor()